# How generate email with Velocity and Impex

Tags: java, email, velocity, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have create a vm file for Template email, I create the vm file for body and for subject. Now I must create the impex with EmailPage and RenderTemplate, someone know that I configure these two (EmailPage, RenderTemplate). It's first time that implements this schema.

Below find the email template:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vosb.png)

Comment: You are trying to adress multiple issues in your question. Try doing what was asked by first not using another thread (instead send the email from within the current thread) and not using velocity (instead use a string constant first for what should be the contents produced by the velocity template). The you can move on from there by adding the thread and velocity template one by one.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker can you give me an example please?

Comment: Hybris documentation contains lots of infos about impex. What exactly is it that you don't understand about impex? This question is still too broad.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I don't understand how to create an email template via impex. I have to send an email to an operator who clicks on a certain button, the email template is the one attached in the photo. I have already created the vm file for the body.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below for detail explanation of creating custom emails in SAP Commerce

[Create Custom Email in SAP Commerce](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/8ad26e9786691014b56dfd3fe3f531ef.html?version=1811)